# How to perform operation on random pairs of RDD elements?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I want to perform operation on random pairs of RDD elements such that takes 1 from larger number and add it to smaller.

For example,let this be our random pairs:
`(23,-52),(3,2),(5,-2),(29,0)`.
After we perform given operation on this pairs,we get RDD something like this:
`(22,2,3,-51,-1,4,28,1)`.

Another example:
`(3,23,-2,5,0,2,-52,29)`.

How to implement solution for this problem?

---

The input RDD is this (3,23,-2,5,0,2,-52,29).I have to perform given operation on random combinations of this RDD-s elements.I have to perform given operation for example on this combinations of this RDD-s elements:(23,-52),(3,2),(5,-2),(29,0) or on this combinations:(2,-52),(29,-2),(0,5),(23,3).

Comment: What is the input of the first RDD?

Comment: What do you mean by "input of the first RDD"?

Comment: Your first RDD isn't pairs. You've said "given pairs", you get no pairs.

Comment: Yes, I see that. You said "After we perform **given operation** on this pairs"... What is the **input** for the output of that **operation** for the "first problem"?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry for not replying earlier.I was waiting results of coronavirus test.It is negative.The input RDD is this (3,23,-2,5,0,2,-52,29).I have to perform given operation on random combinations of this RDD-s elements.I have to perform given operation for example on this combinations of this RDD-s elements:(23,-52),(3,2),(5,-2),(29,0) or on this combinations:(2,-52),(29,-2),(0,5),(23,3).What are random combinations is not relevant,what is relevant is to perfom given operation on some random combionations.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform your operation in map step and then remove pairs using flatMap.

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((23,-52),(3,2),(5,-2),(29,0)))
val rdd2 = rdd.map(s =>
    s._1 > s._2 match {
      case true => (s._1 - 1, s._2 + 1)
      case false => (s._1 + 1, s._2 - 1)
    }
  ).flatMap(s => Seq(s._1, s._2))

  println(rdd2.collect().mkString(" "))
```

output : `2 3 22 4 -1 -51 28 1`

Comment: I think using pattern matching would make `s._1`, `s._2` look cleaner, and you could do `println(rdd2.collect().mkString(" "))`